# Existence of a resonance (or lack of it) for Schrodinger operators

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

In dimension 1, consider two potentials $V_1,V_2\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, both of them decaying exponentially fast at $\pm\infty$. Suppose that the Schrodinger operator $$
L_1=-\partial_x^2+V_1,
$$
does indeed have a resonance at $\lambda=0$. My question is, if we assume that $V_2$ is sufficiently close to $V_1$, is there any additional hypothesis we can make on $V_2$ to ensure that the operator $$
L_2=-\partial_x^2+V_2,
$$
also has a resonance? Here, by "sufficiently close" I mean close in some sufficiently strong norm, let's say $$
\Vert V_1-V_2\Vert_{H^2}\leq \varepsilon
$$
for some $0<\varepsilon\ll 1$, for instance. In other words, is there any way to check if a small perturbation of a Schrodinger operator with a resonance also has a resonance?

Comment: What is your definition of "$L_1$ has a resonance at $\lambda=0$"?

Comment: @user10354138 in dimension 1 I would call "a resonance" an eigenfunction $\phi$ that belongs to $L^\infty$ but not to $L^2$. In this case the resonance (if it exists) should be located at the bottom of the continuum spectrum $\lambda=0$. A resonance solves $L_2\phi=0$ with $\phi\in L^\infty\setminus L^2$.